# How to create a multidimensional variable in ilog with Java interface?

Tags: cplex, ilog

I want to model a problem with a variable x[i][j][k].

No where in the reference manual is there mention of how to create a variable with size greater than 1 dimension.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Filog.odms.cplex.help%2Frefjavacplex%2Fhtml%2Filog%2Fcplex%2FIloCplex.html

Answer (score 4):

This snippet shows an example of creating three indexed continuous variable x, x[i][j][t] in [0,1]:

```
  IloNumVar[][][] x = new IloNumVar[numNodes][numNodes][numDays];
  for(int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) 
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < numNodes; j++)
    {
      //cplex is an instance of class IloCplex
      x[i][j] = cplex.numVarArray(numDays, 0, 1); 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Multi-dimensional modeling is very routine.

[Here's an example, provided by IBM.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21399963)

Also, IBM's ["Modeling with IBM ILOG CPLEX CP Optimizer – Practical Scheduling Examples"](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/common/ssi/ecm/en/wsw14076usen/WSW14076USEN.PDF) is actually a very good place to start. It has many multi-dimensional examples, though most as in OPL, which you don't have to use.

[And, Here's a full example that uses 2 dimensions.](http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/cplex80/doc/userman/html/Java_Design_Model22.html)
Specifically, the variable nutrPerFood has both i and j as dimensions.

```
 // nutrPerFood[i][j]   nutrition amount of nutrient i in food j

 double[][] nutrPerFood;
```

and you use that when calling `IloMPModeler`

[This tutorial](http://www.me.utexas.edu/~bard/LP/LP%20Handouts/CPLEX%20Tutorial%20Handout.pdf) is also helpful, to get familiar with the various Ilog calls.

Hope that helps.